# How determine within a dialog form if it was opened as a modal or non-modal dialog by its parent?

Tags: .net, winforms, dialog

I have a dialog form that can be opened as a modal or non-modal dialog. From within the dialog, how can I tell in which manner the dialog was opened, i.e. modal or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Form` class has a [`Modal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.modal.aspx) property:

> You can use this property to determine whether a form that you have obtained from a method or property has been displayed modally.